# How do I access .beam files from other directories in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have successfully compiled my `.erl` files and now the `.beam` files are lying down in my working directory. However, for some reason I need to access those files from another directory... more specifically from the parent directory. The hierarchy is : `...\wkdir\ebin\beam_example.beam`, and I wish to access the `beam_example.beam` from `wkdir`. Is it possible to do this?

Also, I'm using escript, so a valid import may be very likely to solve this problem, though I just can't figure that out.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545694) if you're looking for a way to add a code path relative to where your escript is stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the search path for the `.beam` with the [code:add_path* methods](https://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#add_path-1). If the code server is in `interactive` [mode](https://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#get_mode-0) (it should be), that'd be enough for the VM to locate the module files and load them lazily.